# How use two subsequent MBProgressHUD messages

Tags: iphone, mbprogresshud

I wan to to show a message using the MBProgressHUD  during the uploading via NSURL string. So i code that:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud1 = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES]; 
hud1.labelText = @"sending info ..."; 
hud1.minShowTime =10.0;

NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlToUpload];
```

the 10 second time is in order to wait some time i want user wait. It works, but I would show another message when the first desappear. Using another:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud2 = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES]; 
hud2.labelText = @"SENT!"; 
hud2.minShowTime =2.0;
```

it is not useful, because this message overlaps the first one.
Any tips about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would remove the first HUD in your `-connectionDidFinishLoading` method or wherever you get notification that the string has been uploaded successfully.

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Then you can add your next HUD for 1-2 seconds. By just adding it via a specific time, there is no way to accurately remove the first HUD before the next one shows.

This was taken from the [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) demo project. I would use this to display your timed completion HUD.

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

// The sample image is based on the work by http://www.pixelpressicons.com, http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/ca/
// Make the customViews 37 by 37 pixels for best results (those are the bounds of the build-in progress indicators)
HUD.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"]] autorelease];

// Set custom view mode
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;

HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"Completed";

[HUD show:YES];
[HUD hide:YES afterDelay:3];
```

Comment: can we also set the success message "Done" provided by the MBProgressHUD.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(void)toast:(NSString*) str view:(UIView*)view delegate:(id)delegate  type:(IconType)type{

    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:view animated:YES];

    MBProgressHUD * HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:view];
    [view addSubview:HUD];

    NSString* strImage;
    switch (type) {
        case kNone:
            strImage=nil;
            break;
        case kOK:
            strImage=@"37x-Checkmark.png";//NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
            break;
        case kError:
            strImage=@"ic_cancel_white_24dp.png";//NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:strImage] ];

    // Set custom view mode
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;

    HUD.delegate = delegate;
    HUD.labelText = str;
    HUD.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    [HUD show:YES];
    [HUD hide:YES afterDelay:1.5f];
}
```